# НЕ отрабатывают потоки все итерации

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Народ подскажите пожалуйста, почему в параллельной области в цикле, потоки не отрабатывают все итерации

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#define N  3
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double start_time=0, end_time=0, tick,f;
    int i, j, threads;
    int a[N][N];
    int sum = 0;
    int min;
    cout << "Enter the number of threads: ";
    cin >> threads;
    omp_set_num_threads(threads);
    cout << "A massifi\n";
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 10+1;
            cout << "A[" << i << " " << j << "] = " << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    start_time = omp_get_wtime();


    #pragma omp parallel private ( min ) 
    {
        min = 100;
        #pragma omp for schedule ( static  ) reduction (+:sum)
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                if (min > a[i][j]) {
                    min = a[i][j];
                }
                printf("Thread %d done [%d ; %d]\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i, j);
            }
            sum = min;
        }
        printf("Hello i am %d thread\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
    
        end_time = omp_get_wtime();
        f = end_time - start_time;
        cout << "Time  = " << f << endl;
        cout << "sum=" << sum;
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это потому, что Вы не сказали, как компилятору быть со счетчиками циклов. Если бы объявили счетчики циклов в заголовках циклов, то компилятор бы все правильно сделал (все счетчики были бы приватными), а так, видимо, он какой-то из счетчиков сделал общим. Я немного изменил директиву для OpenMP - мне кажется, что так правильнее для Вашей задачи - в этом случае, команда `printf("Hello i am %d thread\n", omp_get_thread_num());` будет выполняться уже в одном (основном) потоке.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#define N  3
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double start_time=0, end_time=0, tick,f;
    int i, j, threads;
    int a[N][N];
    int sum = 0;
    int min;
    cout << "Enter the number of threads: ";
    cin >> threads;
    omp_set_num_threads(threads);
    cout << "A massifi\n";
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 10+1;
            cout << "A[" << i << " " << j << "] = " << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    start_time = omp_get_wtime();


//    #pragma omp parallel private ( min ) 
    {
        min = 100;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule ( static  ) reduction (+:sum)  shared(a) private(i,j) firstprivate(min)
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                if (min > a[i][j]) {
                    min = a[i][j];
                }
                printf("Thread %d done [%d ; %d]\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i, j);
            }
            sum = min;
        }
        printf("Hello i am %d thread\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
    
        end_time = omp_get_wtime();
        f = end_time - start_time;
        cout << "Time  = " << f << endl;
        cout << "sum=" << sum;
        return 0;
}
```